# Validar Hash de hashes

Tags: postgresql, hash, perl

Deseo obtener el valor promedio de acuerdo a las fechas de inicio y fecha fin ingresadas por el usuario. Los registros obtenidos están formados por las fechas solicitadas ($datIni y $datFin) más el tiempo formado por hora y minuto.

Agradeceré su apoyo para validar la creación del hash de hashes (%HoH). Se ve que el primer signo es un **{**, y de acuerdo a la referencia mostrada más abajo ésta debería ser un **(**.

Comparto el código:

```perl
do {
    # Ejecuto consulta a la base de datos creando las variables para
    # verificar que existen registros con valor.
    while (existan registros) {
        $fecha = reg->{‘date’};
        $fecha = reg->{‘hh_mm’};
        $fecha = reg->{‘valor’};
        if ($valor != not ‘null’) {
            $med++; # total mediciones aumenta
            $hora_valor += $valor;
            # Asignación de valores al %HoH
            $HoH{$aux_dateini}{$hm} = $valor;
        }
    }
} while ( $datIni->add(days => 1) <= $datFin );
```

Lo imprimo y se muestra así:

```perl
print Dumper (\%HoH);
```

$VAR1=**{**‘2023-01-01’=>{’00:08’=>’-23’, ’01:18’=>’-27’,…, ’23:59’=>’399’},’2023-01-02’=>{’00:08’=>’41’, ’01:14’=>’-37’,…, ’23:59’=>’111’}**}**

Mi pregunta es: ¿Estoy creando bien el %HoH? Ya que en base a
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perl-multidimensional-hashes/
indica éste otro formato, donde el primer signo es un **(** y no **{**.

```perl
my %company = (
    'Sales' => {
        'Brown' => 'Manager',
        'Smith' => 'Salesman',
        'Albert' => 'Salesman', 
    },
    'Marketing' =>  {
        'Penfold' => 'Designer',
        'Evans' => 'Tea-person',
        'Jurgens' => 'Manager', 
    },
    'Production' => {
        'Cotton' => 'Paste-up',
        'Ridgeway' => 'Manager',
        'Web' => 'Developer', 
    },
); 
  
print "Traversing hash using For loop:\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, es correcta la construcción. El problema está en la función Dumper del módulo Data::Dumper. Aunque es una buena solución para ver el contenido de estructuras complejas, a veces la salida hay que entenderla bien.

Mira, si creamos una estructura hash de hashes de forma directa, el resultado es el que muestras:

```bash
perl -E ' %HoH=( "2023-01-01" => {"00:08"=>"-23" }, "2023-01-02" => { "00:08"=>"41" } );
use Data::Dumper;
say Dumper \%HoH;'
$VAR1 = {
          '2023-01-02' => {
                            '00:08' => '41'
                          },
          '2023-01-01' => {
                            '00:08' => '-23'
                          }
        };
```

En cambio, si en vez de Dumper usamos Dump, y le indicamos el nombre de la variable, saldrá de forma correcta:

```bash
perl -E ' %HoH=( "2023-01-01" => {"00:08"=>"-23" }, "2023-01-02" => { "00:08"=>"41" } );
use Data::Dumper;
say Data::Dumper->Dump([\%HoH],["*HoH"]);'
%HoH = (
         '2023-01-01' => {
                           '00:08' => '-23'
                         },
         '2023-01-02' => {
                           '00:08' => '41'
                         }
       );
```

Este problema está comentado en el módulo Data::Dumper::Simple:
https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper::Simple#The-Problem

Con ese módulo vemos bien las estructuras:

```bash
perl -MData::Dumper::Simple -E '%HoH=( "2023-01-01" => {"00:08"=>"-23" }, "2023-01-02" => { "00:08"=>"41" } ); say Dumper(%HoH) '
%HoH = (
         '2023-01-02' => {
                           '00:08' => '41'
                         },
         '2023-01-01' => {
                           '00:08' => '-23'
                         }
       );
```

También lo puedes solventar si instalas cualquiera de otros módulos Data::Dumper, como el más moderno Data::Printer o Data::Dump.

Importante: debes entender el porqué se usa '(' en lugar de '{'.

En [perldoc perldata](https://github.com/perldocES/perldoc-es/blob/master/pod/translated/perldata.pod) lo tienes explicado. Busca por la frase "Este operador es cómodo para inicializar un hash:". Básicamente, con un '(' estás inicializando la estructura, mientras que con un '{' estás indicando que se trata de un hash anónimo, y por lo tanto la referencia debes almacenarla en una variable o contenedor escalar. Tienes explicado qué son las referencias en [perldoc perlref](https://github.com/perldocES/perldoc-es/blob/master/pod/translated/perlref.pod).

Mira estos dos ejemplos:

```perl
my %hash     = ( a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 ); # declaramos y definimos un hash
my $hash_ref = { a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 }; # declaramos y definimos una referencia a un hash
```

Tienes ejemplos de cómo tratar con hashes de hashes en el documento [perldoc perldsc](https://github.com/perldocES/perldoc-es/blob/master/pod/translated/perldsc.pod#hashes-de-hashes---), sección HASHES DE HASHES.